# Django 2.0 website running on a Django 4.0 backend

Tags: python-3.x, django, github, heroku

I am using an old version of Windows, windows 7 to be precise and it seems to only be compatible with Python 3.4 which supports Django 2.0 but heroku doesn't support it anymore
So I want to know if I can manually edit the requirements to Django 4.0 and the required Python version in github.

I haven't yet tried anything as I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using docker to run your application:

https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/django/

This would allow you to set your python and Django version.

Comment: Didn't understand it
Will this help in deployment

Comment: It might. Heroku supports docker: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker

Comment: That is,I can manually change the Python and Django version with it

Comment: You're going to need to use [an _ancient_ version of Docker](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/releases) on Windows 7.